# Rockbox not detecting ipod mount

Tags: mount, ipod, rockbox

The rockbox utility isn't detecting my ipod in the "select your device in the filesystem" drop down list.

The ipod is detected with other programs.

Any ideas?

- Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.
- Ipod 5g 80gb.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a fifth generation iPod? I'm running Rockbox on an iPod 6th generation, which is not yet supported by Rockbox Utility. What are you trying to accomplish? You should be able to install Rockbox without Rockbox utility, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Rockbox Utility fails to detect the mount point of your iPod, it is no big deal. I had the exact same issue with my Sansa Clip Zip. Simply:

- Mount the iPod with your file manager (e.g. `Thunar`)
- In `Configuration > Select your device in the FS` select the appropriate mount point
- In `Configuration > Select your audio player` select `iPod Video 5th gen`

  - Do make sure that this is indeed the device that you have, and that [this very Apple device](http://www.rockbox.org/wiki/IpodPort) is actually [supported by Rockbox](http://www.rockbox.org/wiki/TargetStatus#Current_status_of_stable_targets)!
- Hit OK

To be able to install Rockbox on your music player, Rockbox utility only needs to know the mount point and the correctly specified device (and that the device be supported!). In any case, before performing the installation read the manual for your device (which you can download from the `Manual` tab).